# EmberJS: How do I move stuff out of the application controller?

Tags: ember.js

I have found that nice example of how to display notifications within ember [1]. After noticing it does not work so well with the current ember versions, I created a jsbin and fixed what seemed to be broken: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/decojele/1/edit

I was thinking about putting something like that into its own module, so it can be easily added to existing ember applications. However, the first thing that does not seem to be very suitable for something like this is that it relies on methods and fields (like the notifications array) that are kept within the application controller:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({

  notifications: Em.A()
  // .... 
  //please see jsbin for the other stuff
})
```

This is picked up by a Collection view, which handles the actual rendering.

```
App.NotificationContainerView = Ember.CollectionView.extend({
  contentBinding: 'controller.notifications'
  // .... 
  //please see jsbin for the other stuff
});
```

As far as I currently understand how controllers work is that they depend on the currently active route and I so far haven't been able to put what currently is inside the ApplicationController into something more specific like a NotificationController. Is there a good way to do this? Or is this probably something I am just overthinking?

[1] http://aaron.haurwitz.com/#!/posts/growllike-notifications-with-emberjs

Answer (score 0):

As described here [1], if `render` is used instead of the `view` helper, the appropriate controller is called as well. So, that actually seems to work: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/decojele/2/edit?html,js,console,output

[1] http://darthdeus.github.io/blog/2013/02/10/render-control-partial-view/